# Using Petrel's Reference Project Tool in Petrel from Command Line in Windows

Tags: cmd, copy, petrel

I have a number of Petrel projects which I update on a regular basis. I use Reference Project Tool across all my projects by opening each of them manually, however I'd like to establish if this is possible to automate.

I found couple of references on starting up Petrel from CMD window:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98ce26e7-f320-4c2c-a060-ff7c106deb4a/starting-program-in-silent-mode-using-powershell

[Is it possible to run Petrel in batch mode from a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803393/is-it-possible-to-run-petrel-in-batch-mode-from-a-windows-service)

Is there any guidance for running Petrel's tools (such as RPT) in command line?

I would be grateful for any help!

Many thanks,

Magda